# different amount of rows after merging two dataframes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe which I merge with another dataframe by the column `EQ_NR`.

Here is the Structure of the first dataframe: (Rows: 320816)

Here ist the second one: (Rows: 135818)

After merging I have one dataframe with 'TA' added from the second dataframe to the first one by the value of 'EQ_NR'.

The problem is that I have 320816 rows BEFORE merging and 320871 AFTER merging the two dataframes. What could happen that there are 55 more rows than in the basic data?

I need the Data to do some calculations and the 55 more rows distort the results of the calculations...

Comment: this may be because there is a one-to-many relationship between EQ_NR and TA in the second dataframe.

Comment: it's very nice of you to provide a second DF with zero matching `EQ_NR`... ;)

Comment: oh im sorry for that... i edit it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with duplicates in joining column `NR`.

In sample there are duplicated values `100363` and `100594`.

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NR':[100363,100363,100363, 100365],
                   'B':[4,5,6,7],
                   'C':[7,8,9,7]})

print (df1)
   B  C       NR
0  4  7  100363
1  5  8  100363
2  6  9  100363
3  7  7  100365

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'NR':[1001380363,1001380363,1001380363,1001380363],
                   'B':[4,5,6,8],
                   'C':[7,8,9,3]})

print (df2)
   B  C       EQ_NR
0  4  7  1001380363
1  5  8  1001380363
2  6  9  1001380363
3  8  3  1001380363
```

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['NR']))
    B_x  C_x       NR  B_y  C_y
0     4    7  100363    4    7
1     4    7  100363    5    8
2     4    7  100363    6    9
3     4    7  100363    8    3
4     5    8  100363    4    7
5     5    8  100363    5    8
6     5    8  100363    6    9
7     5    8  100363    8    3
8     6    9  100363    4    7
9     6    9  100363    5    8
10    6    9  100363    6    9
11    6    9  100363    8    3
```

EDIT1:

If dataframe `df2` have no duplicates data in `NR`, use:

```
print (df1)  
  ART     DAT   LEIST_DAT    KD BW       NR MATERIAL  \
0    AF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
1    AF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
2    AF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
3    AF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
4    AF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
5    AF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
6    AF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
7    AF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     E  100594   S   
8    AF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100594   S   

   KW_WERT  NETTO_EURO          TA  
0    0.150       18.90         H  
1    0.145       18.27         H  
2    0.145       18.27         NaN  
3    0.150       18.90         H  
4    0.150       18.90         NaN  
5    0.145       18.27         H  
6    0.150       18.90         H  
7    3.011      252.92         AN  
8    3.412      429.91         AN  

print (df2)
       NR         TA
0  100363  Sonstiges
1  100704  Sonstiges
2  100823  Sonstiges
3  100985  Sonstiges
4  100774          D
5  100790          D
6  100097        NaN
```

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['NR'], how='left', suffixes=('','_new')))
  ART     DAT   LEIST_DAT      KD MW_BW       NR MATERIAL  \
0    F  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
1    F  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
2    F  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
3    F  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
4    F  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
5    F  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
6    F  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100363   S   
7    F  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     E  100594   S   
8    F  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  P     B  100594   S   

   KW_WERT  NETTO_EURO          TA     TA_new  
0    0.150       18.90           H  Sonstiges  
1    0.145       18.27           H  Sonstiges  
2    0.145       18.27         NaN  Sonstiges  
3    0.150       18.90           H  Sonstiges  
4    0.150       18.90         NaN  Sonstiges  
5    0.145       18.27           H  Sonstiges  
6    0.150       18.90           H  Sonstiges  
7    3.011      252.92          AN        NaN  
8    3.412      429.91          AN        NaN
```

Comment: yes there are duplicated values but they are neccesary. Can i handle that somehow?

Comment: You can drop them. Is it possible in real data?

Comment: i dont think so because its possible that the same EQ_NR has multiple values.. i need a merge that exactly handles the rows in the basic file and fills only the TA in the row with the EQ_NR...

Comment: I add sample for demonstrating. Each value `1001380363` from `df1` is duplicated, because in second `df2` are 2 values `1001380363`, because one-to-many relationship.

Comment: basically i understand what is the problem but your sample isnt the solution?! and also it doesnt explain why there are more rows in the new dataframe as in the basic dataframe...

Comment: Sorry, maybe my prevois sample wasnt so good, I rather add another better. First and second `df` have 4 rows and output has 12 rows.

Comment: ehm i guess i have to add that the first dataframe where TA isnt merged in has more columns... i will edit that... Im sorry for that..

Comment: I add output of changed data in question. How does it work?

Comment: i tried it right now. Now i have even more less rows. Instead of 320000 now i only have 314000... thats a bigger difference than before...

Comment: Interesting. Whats happen? Why there is less rows?

Comment: im searching for the differences... it takes a little bit in 320000 rows.. ^^

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you can use pandas for search - e.g. - `print (df2[df2.duplicated(subset=['EQ_NR'], keep=False)])` - get all duplicated rows by column `EQ_NR`

Comment: with your idea i get this error: TypeError: duplicated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep'

Comment: Interesting, what is your version of pandas? For me it works nice.

Comment: Hmmm, it is not new [function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) - maybe some typo?

Comment: i got pandas 0.16.2

Comment: i copied your text and just changed the dataframe names ;)

Comment: Sorry, I asked it before, but I forget for it.

Comment: In older version it is a bit complicated - `print (df2[df2.EQ_NR.isin(df2.EQ_NR[df2.EQ_NR.duplicated()].unique())])`

Comment: i checked if there are duplicated EQ_NR and there were 1. But it didnt solve the Problem. I still have more rows after the merge than i have before.. its little bit frustrating...

Comment: Do you chack also duplicates in `df1`? `print (df1[df1.EQ_NR.isin(df1.EQ_NR[df1.EQ_NR.duplicated()].unique())])`

Comment: in my df1 there are duplicates in EQ_NR, but in the row there are different values. So i know that there are duplicates in df1. In df2 now there arent duplicates anymore..

Comment: Ok, give me a sec, i add solution. But one question - second df2 has only 2 columns with real data?

Comment: sorry didnt worked... now i have again more rows and values after merging..

Comment: I think it is weird. If in dataframe df2 are not duplicated in column `EQ_NR` then it has to works nice. Are you sure there are not duplicates?

Comment: so first  a big thanks to you that you were so patient and tried to help me. Now i found the problem. The main problem is the communication in the office. I got the second df from colleagues which assured me that there are no duplicates in there. but there were duplicates. From 136000 rows i reduced it on 110000 rows. now it works.. thanks once again.

Comment: Glad can help you. Btw, maybe if something similar in the future, maybe the best is send file to other eyes for checking. And if data are not confidental and not big for gmail, I can help you check it or some colleague. Nice day!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add only one column you can use [map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```
In [290]: df1['TA2'] = df1.EQ_NR.map(df2.set_index('EQ_NR').TA)

In [291]: df1
Out[291]:
  FAK_ART     FAK_DAT   LEIST_DAT      KD_CRM MW_BW       EQ_NR MATERIAL  KW_WERT  NETTO_EURO          TA  TA2
0    ZPAF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  T-HOME ICP     B  1001380363   B60ETS    0.150       18.90         SDH  AAA
1    ZPAF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  T-HOME ICP     B  1001380363   B60ETS    0.145       18.27         SDH  AAA
2    ZPAF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  T-HOME ICP     B  1001380363   B60ETS    0.145       18.27         NaN  AAA
3    ZPAF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  T-HOME ICP     B  1001380363   B60ETS    0.150       18.90         SDH  AAA
4    ZPAF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  T-HOME ICP     B  1001380363   B60ETS    0.150       18.90         NaN  AAA
5    ZPAF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  T-HOME ICP     B  1001380363   B60ETS    0.145       18.27         SDH  AAA
6    ZPAF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  T-HOME ICP     B  1001380363   B60ETS    0.150       18.90         SDH  AAA
7    ZPAF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  T-HOME ICP     E  1001380594   B60ETS    3.011      252.92  DSLAM/MSAN  NaN
8    ZPAF  2015-12-10  2015-12-31  T-HOME ICP     B  1001380594   B60ETS    3.412      429.91  DSLAM/MSAN  NaN
```

where df2:

```
In [288]: df2
Out[288]:
        EQ_NR   TA
0  1001380363  AAA
```

NOTE: `df2.EQ_NR` must be unique, otherwise you'll get `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` exception. `df1.EQ_NR` may have duplicates...